# how can make post request for nested json in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have this API json in postman

so the "data" is an object insaid the API

```
{
    "data":{
    "title":"upload api",
    "content":"upload api to the user and show it in the app by id",
    "userid":1
    }
}
```

I want to make post request in flutter to send data to my API

Comment: Present what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you searched for how to do this?

Comment: Here's a codelab on how to do it with the http package: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data

Comment: there is an object in my API that why is not work i want to make it nested

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.